# In .bash_profile already set the path but still got '-bash: mysql: command not found'

Tags: mysql, macos, shell, ipython, bash

I'm quite frustrated that I got the error message trying to use `ipython` or `mysql` from the terminal in OSX. It used to work just fine, but now I got the error message.
Even if I navigated to where mysql is installed, I still get the error message:

```
Bruces-MacBook-Pro:bin bruce$ pwd
/usr/local/mysql/bin
Bruces-MacBook-Pro:bin bruce$ ls
innochecksum            mysqlbinlog
lz4_decompress          mysqlcheck
my_print_defaults       mysqld
myisam_ftdump           mysqld-debug
myisamchk           mysqld_multi
myisamlog           mysqld_safe
myisampack          mysqldump
mysql               mysqldumpslow
mysql_client_test_embedded  mysqlimport
mysql_config            mysqlpump
mysql_config_editor     mysqlshow
mysql_embedded          mysqlslap
mysql_install_db        mysqltest_embedded
mysql_plugin            mysqlxtest
mysql_secure_installation   perror
mysql_ssl_rsa_setup     replace
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql     resolve_stack_dump
mysql_upgrade           resolveip
mysqladmin          zlib_decompress
Bruces-MacBook-Pro:bin bruce$ mysql
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

I did some search, and noticed that I should add the path to the `$PATH` variable in the `.bash_profile`, now I just use `less .bash_profile` to check if this is on my path, below is what I got:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"

export PATH="/Users/bruce/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"

export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:$PATH"

export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PATH"

export PATH="/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages"

export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"

export PATH="/Users/bruce/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"

export PATH="/bin:$PATH"

export PATH="/usr/sbin:$PATH"

export PATH="/sbin:$PATH"

export PATH="/opt/X11/bin:$PATH"

.bash_profile (END)
```

(NOTICE: I have several `.bash_profilexxxx` files here under the home folder. Do I need to modify some of them? Like

```
.bash_profile
.bash_profile-anaconda.bak
.bash_profile-anaconda2.bak
.bash_profile.macports-saved_2015-12-29_at_23:07:52
.bash_profile.pysave
```

)

And it seems that I can't find `.bash_profile.pysave` directly under the home folder, but only available use `ls -a` command? If I need to modify this file, how?

Comment: try `source ~/.bash_profile` and then `mysql`

Comment: oh btw. you overwrite your PATH in the Python/2.7 line :-) you are missing the `:$PATH`

Comment: @Rufinus, thanks. I added this. I see what the problem is now. Since I have 2 disks in my laptop. Some of the files are backed up in the older disk that have the same name, and sometimes I just got messed up with the paths and names of files. The `.bash_profile` I edited is not the one under my home folder. Lol, it bothers me for a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out why this is happening. I have two disks in my laptop. And many of the files are backed up in the older disk that have the same name. So the `.bash_profile` which I edited is actually on the older disk, which is not under my home folder.